# Avoid code duplication for nearly identical logic applied to slightly different entity classes?

Tags: entity-framework, interface, linq-to-entities, entities

Suppose I have a database-backed menu using the Entity Framework with "Item" and "Category" entities.

I have two classes (ItemMappingState and CategoryMappingState) that are virtually identical and do the same thing (manage external mappings onto items and categories), but one works with an Item, and the other works with a Category.  The only real difference between the classes (and what prevents me from just making the manager classes generic based on an interface) is that Item has a property called MappedItems and Category has a property called MappedCategories.

Since these properties are used in the Linq-To-Entities query, I don't think I can make any kind of common interface, because the interface method/property won't be translated correctly in the Linq-To-Entities query at runtime (correct me if I'm wrong).

It's really bugging me that I have these two fairly large classes that are virtually identical, line for line, and I cannot refactor this into a single class that works with both types because they're entity types.  I suppose I could probably add a runtime type-check for the line that differs and cast to the concrete types, but I'd still need an interface for all the other properties that are the same.

The bottom line here is whether or not it's possible to create a common interface for EF types and actually be able to use them in Linq-To-Entities queries.

For example:

```
interface IItems {
    Guid ID {get;set;}
    ICollection<IID> Items {get;set;}
}

interface IID {
    Guid ID {get;set;}
}

class A: IItems {
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public ICollection<AItem> Items {get;set;} //Navigation property
}

class AItem: IID {
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
}

class B: IItems {
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public ICollection<BItem> Items {get;set;} //Navigation property
}

class BItem: IID {
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
}

class AManager {
    public IEnumerable<Guid> GetItemIDs(Guid id) {
        return DbContext.Set<A>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id).Select(x => x.Items.ID);
    }
}

class BManager {
    public IEnumerable<Guid> GetItemIDs(Guid id) {
        return DbContext.Set<B>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id).Select(x => x.Items.ID);
   }
}
```

---

As you can see, AManager and BManager are virtually identical.  They do the same thing; they have identical signatures, they effectively run the same query with the same property names.  The problem is that they are pulling data from two different tables, so I have to use a concrete type when getting the Set from the DbContext.  Since that must be the case, the queries cannot be written against a common interface like IID.  What I'd like to do is have a single manager like this:

```
class Manager<TQueryInterface,TEntity> where TQueryInterface:IItems where TEntity:IItems {
    public IEnumerable<Guid> GetItemIDs() {
        return DbContext.Set<TQueryInterface,TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id).Select(x => x.Items.ID); //query written against TQueryInterface, but runs against table for TEntity in the database
    }
}
```

or perhaps just

```
class IItemsManager<TEntity> 
  where TEntity:IItems 
{
  public IEnumerable<Guid> GetItemIDs() 
  {
    //query written against IItems, but runs against table for TEntity in the database
    return DbContext
      .Set<IItems,TEntity>()
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id)
      .Select(x => x.Items.ID); 
    }
}
```

This is a simple case, but demonstrates the problem.  There seems to be no way to write complex queries that are identical in structure but act on different tables in EF, because the DbSet (and therefore the query itself) must be tied to a concrete type, not a common interface.  The Set method would have to acknowledge a query interface type separate from, but implemented by a concrete entity type.  Essentially, it's separating out the interface from the entity type and specifying both, so that one identifies the table and the other identifies the querying interface.

Comment: This article is claiming that interfaces on entities is an anti-pattern, but in this case, there really are two distinct classes that would need a common interface almost property-for-property, and it would allow for a single class to run logic on either of them, eliminating code duplication.

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to write Linq-To-Entities queries for an interface, but have them run against the table for the underlying concrete types.   For example: IRepository<ICatalogType>().GetQuery().Select(x => x.ID), such that it would select the ID from the concrete entity represented by ICatalogType interface.  Perhaps I could create a version of IRepository that accepts two generic parameters, the Interface as well as the underlying concrete type?

Comment: Digging into the framework, I don't even know if it's possible to get a DbSet<T> for an interface, as there's an error string named "CannotCallGenericSetWithProxyType".  I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Another question could be why you don't normalize the slight difference, so you really have only one `Category` that's related to *specific* stuff that's in `CategoryMappingState` currently.

Comment: Could you provide some code with your problem scenarios? As you can see from http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx EF supports inheritance for entities with different mapping to DB strategies (it looks like your case is closer to TPC aka Table per Concrete class)

Comment: I could have two different entities inheriting from the same type, but that's not the issue.  If I have Employee and Manager both inheriting from Person, that allows me to define the common fields in Person, but it it doesn't allow me to write queries using the Person type, but pulling data from the Employee or Manager tables.  To get an (IQueryable<T>) DbSet<T> object, T has to be a concrete type. There doesn't seem to be a way to get an IQueryable<T> where T is a common type or interface, but at the same time tell EF to actually run the query against a specific table/entity.

Comment: Gert.  I'm not sure what you mean by normalize the slight difference.  The problem isn't just that there's a slight difference; like I said, I could have the properties of interest all be identical or provide a runtime type check for the differing property, but the bigger issue is that I cannot use the same code against two different entities, even if all their properties are identical.  I mean,  if I had two entity classes named A and B and they both had a single property named ID as a common interface,  I could not write a generic class that selects ID from either table.

Comment: Maybe I will add a little more info with code to this question; I'm trying to keep it simple without oversimplifying it.

Comment: There, I added some code.

Comment: @Triynko, I haven't run your code yet but do you suggest that `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()` fails with CannotCallGenericSetWithProxyType error when you call it and specify concrete subclass of yout `IItems`? P.S. if you want commenter to be notified about your reply use `@` such as @SergGr

Comment: @SergGr  No, I'm suggesting that DbContext.Set<T> cannot accept an Interface type for T, so I cannot write queries against an interface.  To do so, the framework would probably require an overload like DbContext.Set<TQuery,TEntity>, accepting both an interface type for the query as well as a concrete entity type (which must inherit TQuery) in order to know which table to run the query against.

Comment: @Triynko Why do you need one more parameter? Why do you need to pass interface there as a type parameter at all? Why restricition `where TEntity:IItems` is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

I have code (renamed entities) that most likely could be modified for your use:

```
public interface IProductDO { }
public class Product1DO : IProductDO { }
public class Product2DO : IProductDO { }

public async Task<IProductDO> GetProductAsync(Expression<Func<IProductDO, bool>> predicate)
{
  var result = await _context.Product1s
    .Where(predicate)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync() as Product1DO;
}
```

So I'd imagine you could do this or something very similar:

```
class IItemsManager<TEntity> 
  where TEntity:IItems 
{
  public IEnumerable<Guid> GetItemIDs() 
  {
    return DbContext
      .Set<TEntity>()
      // this cast may not even be necessary
      // depends on if the linq query is aware of the generic constraint
      .Where<IItems>(x => x.ID == id)
      .FirstOrDefault()
      .Select(x => x.Items.ID); 
    }
}
```